# How to read from string?

Tags: c#, function, datetime, methods, datetimepicker

I'm trying to learn how to schedule pictures depending on what time a user has selected.

Here is code with questions:

```
private void startjob()
{
     string theDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
     DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
     {
         DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 9, 10, 0, 0); //How Do I make this to read the string that is converted from DateTimePicker instead of this?
         DateTime end = new DateTime(2009, 12, 10, 12, 0, 0); //How Do I make this to read the string that is converted from DateTimePicker instead of this?
         DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
         if ((now > start) && (now < end))
         {
         //match found
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you arer trying to do, but `DateTimePicker1.Value` is  `DateTime`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) returns the `DateTime` object. You're trying to convert to and from a string type unnecessarily.

```
DateTime start = DateTimePickerStart.Value;
DateTime end = DateTimePickerEnd.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing your controls are named as DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2:

```
private void startjob()
{
    DateTime start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime end = DateTimePicker2.Value;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if ((now > start) && (now < end))
    {
    //match found
    }
}
```

DateTimePicker.Value property is a DateTime object itself, hence your code can be simplified, no need to convert to string.

Comment: Thanks you for your opinion. His answer was not displayed when I started writing mine. Does the fact that I was a bit slower downgrade the value of my answer?

Comment: + 1 for not being a twat like Rohit.

Comment: +0: While technically correct your answer does not explain why your code works and what was wrong with original code.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Although I thought my code is pretty straightforward, I have edited it and added a brief explanation based on your comment.